# Is it possible/reasonable to use multimembership slope term?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, multilevel-analysis

I have been reading about multimembership models, in which there is a random intercept effect for each level, and an observation can belong to more than one of the levels - a simple example of a linear model like this might be:

$$
Y_{i} = \sum_{K=1}^K \alpha_K W_{i,K}
$$

Where alpha is the random intercept effect and W is a matrix of 1s and 0s with each row indicating the memberships of K categories of observation i. (W can also be weights. [More details here.](https://dera.ioe.ac.uk/6469/1/RR791.pdf))

My question is this: is it valid for the multimembership term to be a slope effect? i.e.,

$$
Y_{i} = \sum_{K=1}^K \beta_K X_{i,K}
$$

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? I haven't found anything about multimember slopes so far in my Googling. Maybe I've misunderstood how to use the multimembership terms, or maybe this would rarely if ever a good solution to having multiple related explanatory variables for each observation.

I think this could be used for modelling the relationship between two continuous variables if you had multiple similar measurements of your explanatory variable for every observation of the response variable. I guess in a way it's the explanatory variable that has multiple membership rather than the response variable.

As an example, say you want to know the relationship between incidence of tick borne illness in humans with the prevalence of ticks in local wild mammals. You have tick counts for a few species of mammal, and you want to use all the tick counts available. Maybe something like this could be used:

```
    Incidence[area] = sum(beta[S] * TickCount[area, S])
```

A regular random slope effect like `beta[S] * TickCount[area, S]` can only take one tick count observation per response observation. Having a separate effect for each species, like `beta1 * TickCount[area, 1] + beta2 * TickCount[area, 2] + ...`  is probably a reasonable thing to do but loses the benefits of random effects.